# Grails/Hibernate criteria to check if a hasMany association contains certain entities

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I have three domain classes in a Grails project:

```
class Conversation {
    static hasMany = [members: ConversationMember]
}

class ConversationMember {
    User user
    static belongsTo = [conversation: Conversation]
}

class User {
    String name
}
```

I want to construct a Hibernate criteria that allows me to, given two Users, return all Conversations that contain ConversationMembers that reference those two users.

That is to say, if I have Conversation A with Josh and Jordyn and Conversation B between Josh and Sam, and Conversation C between Josh, Jordyn and Sam, this criteria given Josh and Jordyn should return Conversations A and C.

I've tried the following and they don't seem to work:

```
List<Conversation> conversations = Conversation.createCriteria().list() {
    and {
        members {
            ne('user', currentUser)
        }
        members {
            ne('user', conversationMemberToSearch)
        }
    }
}

List<Conversation> conversations = Conversation.createCriteria().list() {
    not {
        or {
            members {
                ne('user', currentUser)
            }
            members {
                ne('user', conversationMemberToSearch)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this without doing something with `sqlRestriction`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlRestriction` in criteria to write native sql or better to write hql query.
Hql will look like: `"from Conversation where :firstUser in members and :secondUser in members"`.
sqlRestriction will be: `"(select count(*) from conversation_members where member_id in (${firstUser.id}, ${secondUser.id}) and conversation_members_id = _this.id) == 2"`, but you should **check tables and field** names. `_this` -> usually represent current main entity in criteria in your case it will be `Conversation`.

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution without using `sqlRestriction` but I'm more open to it if I can still use HQL. So I can put `sqlRestriction ':firstUser in members and :secondUser in members'` or something like that? I haven't been able to find any documentation/examples where HQL is used in a `sqlRestriction` field.